# How to collect only string instances from a collection?

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array, which is comprising of different kind of objects. But I would like to get only the string instances. What i wrote as below :

```
ary = ["11",1,2,"hi",[11]]
ary.select{|e| e.instance_of? String } # => ["11", "hi"]
```

I am looking for an elegant way of doing this, if any.

Answer (score 8):

I would do as below using [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) :

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern === element. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

```
ary = ["11",1,2,"hi",[11]]
ary.grep(String) # => ["11", "hi"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Object#is_a?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) method:

```
ary = ["11", 1, 2, "hi", [11]]
ary.select{|e| e.is_a? String }   

# Output
=> ["11", "hi"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't do better than `grep`, but here's another:

```
ary.group_by(&:class)[String] # => ["11", "hi"]
```